# Javascript setTimeout runs twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home-buzz-1').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});

    setTimeout("$('#home-buzz-2').css('display','inline');$('#home-buzz-2').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});",3000);

    setTimeout("$('#home-buzz-3').css('display','inline');$('#home-buzz-3').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});",4500);
});
```

I'm trying to script an animation on this page with the Fancy Typewriter plugin - which takes the text inside an element, and makes a nice typing animation with it. But the last two divs that have the setTimeout function, run twice. The idea is that I want one div to animate, and then the next one to animate after the previous one has finished. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't pass a string as an argument to `setTimeout`.

Comment: jQuery animate allows you to queue animations so that they're done one after the other : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Does fancyTypewriter have a complete event?

Comment: Wow looking at it, it does! callback – A function that will be called when the effect has ended TADA!

Comment: @dystroy: which does the same thing, basically, only a lot slower :)

Comment: That code won't make it run twice. Any chance there's other code interfering?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem are you saying that when using jquery we should avoid the provided queue functions to queue animations because they're "slower" ? Or did I miss something in your comment ?

Comment: @dystroy: You missed the smiley-face. I'm just in favour of using pure JS when all you need is a simple timeout. It is faster, and that way I hope ppl will appreciate the language more, and use it better.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass a string to setTimeout function, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home-buzz-1').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#home-buzz-2').css('display','inline');
        $('#home-buzz-2').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});}
    ,3000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#home-buzz-3').css('display','inline');
        $('#home-buzz-3').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});}
    ,4500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@zzzzBov is right, JS is a *functional* language:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $('#home-buzz-3').css('display','inline');
    $('#home-buzz-3').fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true});
},4500);
```

So setTimout expects a function to be passed, not a string constant. It's pretty much the same as `$(document).ready(function(){});` <-- you're passing functions as arguments all the time.

Comment: You CAN pass a string to setTimeout (where it will be eval'd, which is evil), however you shouldn't and a function is the preferred way.

Comment: @RichardDalton: Fair enough, but as soon as _eval_ enters the mix, I bail out. Since JSON (either Crockfords plugin, or native support) I have yet to encounter a single real-life case where eval is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

No setTimeouts are needed, the plugin has a callback when it completes.

```
$(function(){
    function addTypeWriter(elemId) {  //You copy pasted the same thing over and over, make a helper function!
        jQuery(elemId).show().fancyTypewriter({type:true, steps:3, timeBetweenSteps:25, 'mouseOver': false, underScore:true, callback: nextOne});
    }  //chaining does the body good. Notice the callback, read the docs!
    var typewriters = ["#home-buzz-1","#home-buzz-2","#home-buzz-3"];  //elements you want to apply the effect to in sequential order
    function nextOne() {  //this is what we call
        if(typewriters.length==0) {  //if length is greater than zero, we have things to run!
            return;
        }
        var elem = typewriters.shift();  //remove first item from the array
        addTypeWriter(elem);  //fire off the annimation
    }
    nextOne(); //start it off
});
```